# Only few images imports in the app using ALAssets compare to photo stream app

Tags: ios

I'm using ALAssetLibrary to access the images and display it from camera roll and other saved albums. The problem is only few of images I'm able to get, where remaining images were not shown while compare to photo stream (native photos app) example : In photo stream if it has 1000 photos and then I accessed using Alasset it will get only few photos say 600 only. what could be the reason for this. Could you please guide a solution for this?

Thanks!

code included

```
[group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if (asset) {
         // We'll get the image from this assets.
    }
}];
```

Comment: Post the code that's pulling the photos.

Comment: I've made the changed the above with snippet.

Comment: Inside the block, you just check if the asset is not nil?

Comment: Yes I've checked. In photo stream it shows 1000 photos. but the inside my app it shows only appropriate say 800 photos. Also note that I don't face any issue with iPhone 5/6 (IOS 7 and IOS8). Is there any issue with latest OS version leads to?